# windows store app: navigate to onother page

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am new in windows store app development and now I am stuck with a problem.
In the application I am working on from a login page I navigate to a search page, in here if a certain condition occurs I want to directly navigate to a third page without showing the search page at all.

So in login page I have:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(searchpage));
```

and in searchpage:

```
private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
  if (certainCondition)
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(thirdPage));
}
```

the problem is that the application never reaches thirdPage...

Thanks in advance for any help given!

Comment: When debugging, are you sure `certainCondition` is true? Further, create a value to put the result of `this.Frame.Navigate` into, such as `var success = this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(thirdPage));`. I'd bet money that there is some issue with the loading of `thirdPage`, and the navigation is failing because of it. Debug and see if it outputs any exceptions. It will not *throw* an exception if it fails though, it will just output to the debug log and return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **OnNavigatedTo** making sure it hits every time you enter the page.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       if (certainCondition)
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(thirdPage));
   }
```

If this is not it then debug the condition to make sure it's not false all the time.